# Detect when mouse leaves via top of page with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

This Jquery problem has been bugging me for a while now. I developed a script, with one function detecting when the mouse leaves via the top of the page. Here is the code:

```
    $(document).bind("mouseleave", function(e)
    {
    console.log(e.pageY);
    if (e.pageY <= 1)
        {    
        now = new Date();           
        for (i=0; i < times.length; i++)
            {
            if (now.getTime() > times[i][0] && now.getTime() < times[i][1])
                {
                    $.fn.colorbox({iframe:true, width:650, height:600, href: "work.html", open: true});          
                }    
            }
        }
    });
```

This works perfectly for me in all browsers. For some reason it works randomly in Chrome and seemingly not at all in Firefox for a friend that tested the site. In my browser (firefox 3.5.3), e.pageY is logged in the console box as a number near 0, however in my friends browser (also firefox 3.5.3) the lowest value is around 240. I have no idea why this is happening considering identical browsers. Does anyone have a clue as to how to debug this, or another more reliable method to detect when the mouse goes out of the webpage via the top? I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Have you tried moving the mouse really quick? Events sometimes doesn't fire if mouse moves quickly.

Comment: If moving very quickly it registers the majority of the time (that is not really a concern). However for testing the mouse is moving extremely slowly

Comment: @vava, I'm just saying that maybe your friend has slower machine/bigger screen and moves mouse fast. That might be the reason for the difference.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem appears if your window scrolls down, add a bunch of `<br/>`s to your page and scroll down one line and you'll see it.

So instead of looking to see if e.pageY <=1, subtract out the scrollTop:

```
if (e.pageY - $(window).scrollTop() <= 1)
    {    
    // do something
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used another technic, almost works for all browsers. The trick is using `$("body")` or `$(window)`.

`$(window)` do not work for IE, but `$("body")` works partially for FF as the body might not fill the whole window.

Here's the full page code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script><script>
  var mouseX = 0;
  var mouseY = 0;
  var theFrame;
$(function() {
    theFrame = $("body"); //$(window) for non-IE
      theFrame.mousemove( function(e) {
        //horizontal distance from edge
        mouseX = Math.min(theFrame.width() - e.pageX, e.pageX);
        //vertical distance from top
        mouseY = e.pageY;
        $("#mx").html(mouseX);
        $("#my").html(mouseY);
      });
    theFrame.mouseout(function() {
        if(mouseY<=mouseX)
            $("#in_out").html("out-top");
        else
            $("#in_out").html("out");
    });
    theFrame.mouseover(function() {
        $("#in_out").html("in");
    });
});
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<span id="in_out"></span>
<br />Hor: <span id="mx"></span>
<br />Ver: <span id="my"></span>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note: in_out, mx, my are for debugging purpose only :P

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('mouseleave', leaveFromTop);

function leaveFromTop(e){
    if( e.clientY < 0 ) // less than 60px is close enough to the top
      alert('y u leave from the top?');
}
```

This [doesn't work](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#position) well on older IE version, because those versions don't report the mouse position as should, but it's good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a vanilla JS solution if you just want something light weight that doesn't need to work in EI

```
/**
 * Trigger an event when the cursor leaves the top of the window
 * @param {*} threshold how close does it need to be to the top
 * @param {*} cb callback function to trigger
 */
function onExit (threshold, cb) {
  threshold = threshold || 60
  var hasExited = false
  document.addEventListener('mouseout', function (e) {
    if (e.clientY < threshold && e.movementY < 0 && !hasExited) {
      hasExited = true
      cb(e)
    }
  })
}
```

**Example Usage:**

```
onExit(20, function() {
  console.log('Mouse has left the top of the window!')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to detect mouseleave without taking in account the scroll bar and the autcomplete field or inspect :

```
document.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(event){

  if(event.clientY <= 0 || event.clientX <= 0 || (event.clientX >= window.innerWidth || event.clientY >= window.innerHeight))
  {

     console.log("I'm out");

  }
});
```

Conditions explanations:

```
event.clientY <= 0  is when the mouse leave from the top
event.clientX <= 0  is when the mouse leave from the left
event.clientX >= window.innerWidth is when the mouse leave from the right
event.clientY >= window.innerHeight is when the mouse leave from the bottom
```

Just keep

```
event.clientY <= 0
```

If you only want to detect exit on top